# Problems using the Python interface of the Berkeley Parser

Tags: python, parsing

I am using the berkeley parser's interface in Python. I want to use the parser by having the input as a string and not a file. In this document, the usage is explained: https://github.com/emcnany/berkeleyinterface/blob/master/examples/example.py

Here is the documentation for the interface
https://github.com/emcnany/berkeleyinterface/blob/master/BerkeleyInterface/berkeleyinterface.py

I am following that guide but when I'm running the code below, nothing happens after reaching the last line and the code never finishes.

```
import os
from BerkeleyInterface import *
from StringIO import StringIO
JAR_PATH = r'C:\berkeleyparser\parser.jar'
GRM_PATH = r'C:\berkeleyparser\english.gr'
cp = os.environ.get("BERKELEY_PARSER_JAR", JAR_PATH)
gr = os.environ.get("BERKELEY_PARSER_GRM", GRM_PATH)
startup(cp)
args = {"gr":gr, "tokenize":True}
opts = getOpts(dictToArgs(args))
parser = loadGrammar(opts)
print("parser loaded")
strIn = StringIO("hello world how are you today")
strOut = StringIO()
parseInput(parser, opts, outputFile=strOut)
```